# Want to add french version to the website and trouble in lauching it due to 'index.html'

Tags: html, github, version-control

1. I want to add a drop-down so that people can see the French version of my website.
2. When I double-click the ‘index.html’ file, it works fine from the local computer, but I’m having trouble hosting it on GitHub. Here is the link to the repository- https://github.com/Kkhurana007/blog_le07decembre.github.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dummy `index.html` file which contain path of original `index.html` file path. Duplicate file for accessing your home page.

```html
<a href="/index.html">My Index Page</a>
```

Comment: Hi @Swapnil, thanks! I did the way you told. Now, the clickable "My Index Page" gets displayed with white background.

Comment: GitHub can find only the main folder .index file. your file is located in subfolder. i will check wait

Comment: Bro I have created a pull request please accept this. I have changed that code I hope I will work lets see what happens , let me know ..

Comment: Thanks @Swapnil. Your help is much appreciated. I created another repository for my personal blog and that works fine. https://github.com/Kkhurana007/my_website

Comment: welcome bro      anytime